# Drupal Managing News "My Saved Search" Views

Tags: drupal, view

I using Drupal Managing News Attribution 6.0 / 1.2
Users can search a word and after users can save this search word.
But all users can see this saved searchs.

I want to show only users own saved searchs. Example Only My SAved Searchs...
I tried add argument but cant.

How can i make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified the version as well as what module you are using to achieve but I think this module works great for saved search -

http://drupal.org/project/views_savedsearches

And you will have to set the permission like which search is accessible by whom and you will surely achieve what you are looking for...

Comment: Hi. Its working fine. Thanks. I have mn_news view and this view included more view 

Defaults Page: Feeds Block: Trend graph Block: Map Page: Search RSS Feed Mode: List Mode: Map OpenLayers Data (Fullscreen) OpenLayers Data (Block) Mode: Trash Mode: Trash (Search) Block: News KML Feed

Module was added all views.

But I want to add to only Page: Search. I must disable other sub views. I tried css display: none but dont worked.

How can i disable for other subviews without Page: Search?